# Transformations with invertible matrix representations are onto

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Let $L \colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ be a linear mapping and let $B$ be a basis for $\Bbb R^n$. Prove that if $[L]_B$ is invertible, then $\operatorname{Range}(L) = \Bbb R^n$.

I really can't see how $[L]_B$ being invertible implies $\operatorname{Range}(L) = \Bbb R^n$. Help?

Answer (score 1):

Given $v\in\mathbb R^n$, express $v$ in base $B$, apply the inverse of $[L]_B$ to it, interprete this as a linear combination, i.e., as a vector $w\in\mathbb R^n$; then observe that $L(w)=v$.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think is: $\det L$ is independent of the basis you choose, so $[L]_B$ being invertible gives $\det L \neq 0$. So $\ker L = \{0\}$ (otherwise?), and: $$\dim \Bbb R^n = \dim \ker L + \dim {\rm Ran}\,L \implies n =   \dim {\rm Ran}\,L.$$ Also: $$\begin{cases} {\rm Ran}\,L \subseteq \Bbb R^n \\ \dim {\rm Ran}\,L = \dim \Bbb R^n = n < +\infty\end{cases} \implies  {\rm Ran}\,L = \Bbb R^n  $$